# Using 3 graphics cards (1 Single and 2 in Crossfire)

Tags: graphics-card

With my current setup, I have to AMD 5770's in crossfire on an [ASRock 890FX Deluxe 4](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/890FX%20Deluxe4/) motherboard (running Windows 7). I was originally wanting to purchase a new AMD 280X to replace the 2 5770's, but I have gotten into CryptoCoin mining and want to keep all three cards.

I want to use the 280X for gaming and as my display, but I also want to use all three cards for mining purposes. Is it possible to have all three cards working in my system at the same time?

(I've looked online and found I can't run all 3 together for gaming, but I haven't been able to find if I can use all 3 in the configuration I want.)

Comment: Its may not be a problem here I suspect but what OS?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Windows 7

Comment: In theory it should be fine.  A system can have an Intel GPU and Nvidia/AMD GPU and function just fine.  You might have to deal with the configuration of software to use a specific device of course.  In this case you would have two devices.  The 280x and the SLI devices but all honesty a single 280x would out perform the SLI devices in crypto currency minning.

Comment: From my experience with scrypt mining, there is a major lag with the mouse/windows when the monitor is being driven by the scrypt miner. You may want to dedicate your igp to your monitors or not mine at 100% intensity on the card driving your monitors. This way, you can still be productive on the macine. Also depending on your setup, get an ac unit for that room. Typically it cost about 2$ per day for electricity of a 600-1000w ac unit. Something to consider if you're mining. I have a few asics mining alt coins and the retun is greater than the investment so i dont mind the elec bill.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to run your 5770s in CrossFire while using another AMD branded card that shares the same driver. This is the same with SLI, as these technologies are scoped to the driver level.

The good news is that you certainly can use the 280x as your main display-driving graphics card and use the 5770s for mining without using CrossFire.

Comment: Will there be any issues with the drivers? or do these cards use the same driver?

Comment: They use the same driver. Once you plug all three cards in at once, they will all show in Catalyst Control Center.